# Представление графа в памяти для быстрого доступа к его элементам

Tags: память, графы, структуры-данных, доступ, организация

Имея большие и очень большие графы размещённые на плоскости, необходимо быстро определять видимые объекты (часть графа в определённом масштабе, когда пользователь что то рассматривает), среди них объекты попадающие под указатель мыши. Граф состоит из узлов и рёбер. Как эффективно организовать представление графа в памяти под эту задачу?
Первое решение разбить пространство на квадраты, те, на квадраты поменьше и тд. Далее определять какие квадраты видны, какие к ним привязаны объекты, и уже дальше работать. Но рёбра могут распологаться на нескольких таких квадратах, возникают прочие другие проблемы.
Второе решение использовать тот факт что граф связан (а может и не связан), вспомнить о рекурсии...
Есть ли решение лучше? Идеи, структуры данных, алгоритмы, когда узлов от 25000 шт и более. Уже какое то время бесполезно просматриваю статьи, литературу

Comment: Если я правильно понял, это больше похоже на классическую задачу вычислительной геометрии - найти точки, попадающие в заданный прямоугольник - чем на задачу на графы. Если не так, объясните подробнее, что значит *определять видимые объекты*.

Comment: Имея плоскость, на которой расположен граф, пользователь может менять масштаб просмотра, координаты вида экрана, что бы рассматривать граф целиком либо его часть так же, как он делал бы это рассматривая google-карту с улицами, перекрёстками.

Могут возникнуть особенности отображения видимых рёбер образованных узлами расположенными за таким прямоугольником, и прочие.

При таком рассмотрении задачи, как найти все такие точки?

Comment: Объясните, чем ваша задача отличается от масштабирования любой другой картинки, а не представления графа на плоскости?

Comment: Если представить граф отражающий улицы города (условно, линиями), то приблизив какой либо фрагмент такого графа он не потеряет в резкости, и при наведении курсора на улицу (ребро графа) возможнно сразу получить "свойства" улицы, изменить их